# Akka actorFor vs passing an ActorRef

Tags: scala, akka

I'm learning Akka and I'm trying to figure out how to get actors talking to each other (let's call them `A` and `B`). It's not a request / response scenario, `A` and `B` are sending each other messages at any time.

At the moment I've got two sibling actors that pass messages in both directions to each other. They're both created directly on the `ActorSystem`. I had initially passed the `ActorRef` of `A` into the constructor of `B`. But I can't pass the `ActorRef` of `B` to the constructor of `A` because it doesn't exist yet, i.e. I can't use this method for circular references.

I've been reading about `actorFor` and this would let me look up an actor using it's path. However, I'm not comfortable with this setup, because if the path changes, it won't be caught by the compiler.

Another alternative, considering every actor has access to it's parent, is to pass the messages from `A` and `B` to the parent and then have the parent pass the message back down to `A` and `B`. But this couples the parent to the message types being passed back and forth.

What are strategies are people using for making actors aware of each other? Am I being too cautious about looking up actors by path?

Comment: Have you tried using `lazy val`s when instantiating your `ActorRef`s? I can imagine this would help resolving the circular dependency. Assuming you use Scala of course...

Comment: I just gave that a go and it works. I didn't know you reference a lazy val before it's defined - crazy stuff! Thanks for the tip. I'll still be interested to know how people feel about passing ActorRefs vs paths.

Comment: Make sure you've read http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/general/addressing.html.

Comment: I would definitely not use the lazy vals approach, for safety and distribution reasons. Have the parent send a message to each to tell them about the identity (actorref) of their sibling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my humble opinion you have three strategies, which I list from the closer to your problem (but also to me the worst pattern, I am sorry)

Strategy 1: you create actor A and actor B, passing actorRef A to the constructor of actor B. Your ping-pong will start from actor B sending a message to actor A, and actor A can simply reply using the sender reference. (or the other way around)

---

Strategy 2: you create a layer in your application which takes care of the naming: it assigns the name at creation of the actor, as well as when querying.  This centralizes the problem in a single point.

---

Strategy 3: You wonder if two siblings actors playing ping-pong are not replacing a better, more modular actor hierarchy where basically each actor communicate only with his parent and his children and has no knowledge about his siblings.

Comment: Strategy 3 does sound the most sensible. I was a little worried that the parents were going to end up doing a lot of wiring, but I guess that's ok because it's the parent's job to coordinate its children (besides, just forwarding messages isn't much work at all).