# How to construct an actor together with its wrapper?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to write an actor called `ActorManager` which wraps another actor called `RealActor`. The idea is that the `ActorManager` can process all messages going in and out of `RealActor`, allowing to add additional logic like filtering or buffering. The outside world is supposed to communicate with the `RealActor` only through its manager, much like in real world.

A first draft would look like this:

```scala
class ActorManager(realActor: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case _ => { /* pre-process messages */ }
  }
}

class RealActor(actorManager: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case _ => { /* actual business logic */ }
  }
}
```

This however raises the question how to construct both actors at once, or more specifically how to define the corresponding `Props` given the circular dependency of the two actors. I'm not sure if the [general `lazy val` pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7508176/1804173) is applicable when defining `Props`.

I also would like to avoid the work-around of constructing one of the two first, combined with introducing an explicit `Register` protocol to connect them.

Comment: Just came across [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819386/akka-actorfor-vs-passing-an-actorref) which I didn't find at first because of its unexpected title. In terms of the solution presented there, my question here specifically addresses the "Strategy 3" case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a case is much better solved by using an actor hierarchy instead of plain actor siblings. Since the main intent here is to hide the `RealActor` from the outside world, it makes much more sense that its `ActorRef` is accordingly wrapped/owned by the outer `ActorManager`.

This means that the `RealActor` reference has to be created within the `ActorManager` scope. This can be achieved by passing the parent an `ActorRef => Props` function, allowing to create the child actor:

```scala
// Parent
class ActorManager(getRealActorProps: ActorRef => Props) extends Actor {
  val realActor = context.actorOf(getRealActorProps(self))
  def receive = {
    case _ => { /* pre-process messages */ }
  }
}

// Child
class RealActor(actorManager: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case _ => { /* actual business logic */ }
  }
}

object RealActor {
  def propsActorManager(getRealActorProps: ActorRef => Props) = 
    Props(new ActorManager(getRealActorProps))
  def propsRealActor(actorManager: ActorRef) = 
    Props(new RealActor(actorManager))

  def props() = 
    Props(new ActorManager(actorManager => propsRealActor(actorManager)))
}
```

Note that it is now even possible to hide the fact that the `RealActor` is wrapped by providing an appropriate `props` definition, which builds the `ActorManager -> RealActor` hierarchy implicitly.

See also [this blog post](https://manuel.bernhardt.io/2016/08/09/akka-anti-patterns-flat-actor-hierarchies-or-mixing-business-logic-and-failure-handling/) why flat actor hierarchies are considered an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Something of this sort may work well for you:

```
import akka.actor._

class Manager extends Actor {

  def realActor: ActorRef = context.child("real")
        .getOrElse(context.actorOf(RealActor.props, "real"))

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg ⇒ realActor forward msg
  }
}    

object RealActor {
  def props: Props = Props(new RealActor)
}

class RealActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ ⇒
  }
}
```

Creating child actor through parent's context seems to be sufficient for creating parent-child hierarchy. The parent can be obtained by calling context.parent in child actor.

Comment: Good point about `context.parent`, the relationship would just be slightly less explicit.